# If condition with string length

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Hi I was given with task to transform xml with one address field to xml with 3 address fields. The condition to be followed is if the number of char in address field of source XML is greater than 40 then go to Address2 field and write the rest of the data in address2 if address2 was also having more than 40 char then go to address 3. I was asked to use XLST and I am not expert in xslt.

Comment: Can you add your sample XML and any XSLT you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

This is a great reference for questions like this: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp

Basically you'd be doing an if statement like this:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length('My String') > 6">
    <!-- Do some stuff here -->
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Link was dead (and edit queue full :-), today it's this one: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp

Comment: @mweber Thanks for the comment, link updated!